# Adding formatting tools to the 'ask question' page on the mobile site

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, editor

The biggest problem on the mobile site (not app) for any Stack Exchange website  is there are no formatting tools at all. This makes asking and answering far more difficult since I have to use the 'full site' option, which is very inconvenient on a 5.2" screen. I am hoping a developer reads this message and adds formatting for mobile-reliant users like me.

Comment: You'd do well to spend a few minutes and learn the Markdown syntax.

Comment: What is markdown syntax?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Should that even be a thing. Why not redesign it so both a re equal?

Comment: If you use the little editor formatting tools, all it does is add the Markdown syntax for you.

Comment: There is no such thing

Answer (score 1):

I usually don't need or use the formatting buttons, except in cases such as [putting a huge amount of text into a code block](//stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14325439).

## ***Psst! It's a secret! They're basically just shortcuts!***

The <kbd>**B**</kbd> and <kbd>*I*</kbd> buttons just put one or two asterisks around the selected text, which the server parses into **bold** and *italic*. *One star* makes *italic*, and **two stars** makes **bold**. `backticks` can create `code spans` as well. You don't even need *these* either, because the HTML `<strong>`, `<em>`, and `<code>` tags are whitelisted and **can** *be* `used` instead.

In fact, there's also [a whole bunch of things](/editing-help#tags) that you *can't* do with the formatting buttons, such as [tags](/questions/tagged/tags), <kbd><kbd></kbd>, and HTML entities.